# R: choose elements from list based on values in vector with same names

Tags: r, list, vector

[Probably this question already has an answer here, but I didn't manage to find one, also because I have some difficulty in formulating it concisely. Suggestions for reformulating the title of the question are appreciated.]

I have

- a list of matrices with different numbers of rows,
- a vector of integer values with the same names as the list's,
- a list of names that appear in the list and vector above,
- an integer variable telling which column to choose from those matrices.

Let's construct, as a working example:

```
mynames <- c('a', 'c')

mylist <- list(a=matrix(1:4,2,2), b=matrix(1:6,3,2), c=matrix(1:8,4,2))

myvec <- 2:4
names(myvec) <- names(mylist)

chooseCol <- 2
```

I'd like to construct a vector having as elements the rows taken from `myvec` and column `chooseCol`, for the names appearing in `mynames`. My attempt is

```
sapply(mynames, function(elem){mylist[[elem]][myvec[elem], chooseCol]})
```

which correctly yields

```
a c 
4 8
```

but I was wondering if there's a faster, `base` (non-`tidyverse`) method of doing this.

Also important or relevant: the order of the names in `mylist` and `myvec` can be different, so I can't rely on position indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `mapply` -

```
mapply(function(x, y) x[y, chooseCol], mylist[mynames], myvec[mynames])

#a c 
#4 8
```

Comment: Nice @Ronak, upvoted.  Does it mean `mapply` somehow works like `purrr::map2_df` ?

Comment: Thank you, this is more elegant. It seems slightly, just slightly slower than `sapply`.

Comment: @AnilGoyal It depends on what we are returning from the function in this case I would say it is similar to `map2_dbl` i.e `purrr::map2_dbl(mylist[mynames], myvec[mynames], ~.x[.y, chooseCol])`

Comment: @pglpm Did you test it on larger sample? How big is your data?

Comment: @RonakShah For now I just repeated the call `1e6` times under `system.time`. But the difference is just some tenths of seconds. I'll apply it to the real case and update you on the timing.

Comment: mapply is pretty much the same as the multi-argument `map` functions from purrrr, like `pmap` and `map2`. The main drawback of mapply is that it is not type-safe like the many `map2_*`, and simplifies the output. Another limitation is that the argument order is not consistent with other functions from purrr, which always have the format `function(data, function, constants)`

Comment: @RonakShah It looks like `mapply` is faster: for my problem, where it's executed rougly `8e6` times with some parallelization, `mapply` yielded a `system.time` of `74.81   18.72  430.34`, whereas `sapply` yielded `75.33   19.79  450.18`. Thank you. I'll just wait a little before accepting your answer, to see if other answers arrive.